# QGIS 3 - how to change size of attribute window?

Tags: dialog, window, qgis

When adding a new feature to a shape file in QGIS 3.4.4. the attributes dialog opens only as a tiny window regardless of the length or number of the attribute columns in the list. I can manually adjust the size of the window but when I add the next features it is tiny again. That soon gets very annoying when many features need to be added.

Here an example screenshot: 
[image]

Is this a bug or can I somewhere change the settings so that the window automatically opens at an appropriate size? I am running QGIS 3 on  MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post but I was having the same issue so I figured I would post how I fixed it. It might have been patched in later releases because I saw there was a bug report submitted.

I'm Running QGIS 3.8 on mac.

open layer properties, navigate to attributes form (icon below source fields). On the top left drop down menu change "Autogenerate" to "drag and drop designer"

This resolved my problem and the attributes form is full size. I had to repeat the process for all shapefiles I was working on.

[default settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY9Bn.png)

[settings to make it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7OQO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Mac, even with the drag & drop option.
Click the small icon in the middle of the top line (right to the "Autogenrate" etc. things).
Select "Provide code in this dialog" and paste:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
        
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

 
def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog

    dialog.setMinimumSize(1200, 800)
```